# flood fill algorithm initialization c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

EDIT: Okay, after a few answers I will make a few corrections:

```
byte r, g, b;
    scr->GetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, (byte)& r, (byte)& g, (byte)& b);
    while (r != (byte)0 && g != (byte)0 && b != (byte)0)
    {
        scr->SetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, (byte)255, (byte)0, (byte)0);
        mid.x++;
        FloodFill(scr, mid);
        mid.x--;
        mid.x--;
        FloodFill(scr, mid);
        mid.y++;
        FloodFill(scr, mid);
        mid.y--;
        mid.y--;
        FloodFill(scr, mid);
    }
```

Plus, before I do anything with the parameters, this is the GetRGB function:

```
void CDIB32::GetRGB(int x, int y, BYTE& r, BYTE& g, BYTE& b)
{
    if (x >= Width() || y >= Height())
        IERROR;

    int off = y * ByteWid() + x * 4;
    b = m_pBits[off];
    g = m_pBits[off+1];
    r = m_pBits[off+2];
}
```

And this is the SetRGB Function:

```
void CDIB32::SetRGB(int x, int y, BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b)
{
    //ASSERT(x < Width() && y < Height());

    int off = y * ByteWid() + x * 4;
    m_pBits[off] = b;
    m_pBits[off+1] = g;
    m_pBits[off+2] = r;
}
```

The assumption of user OzMiz is correct, that the line causing the error. Apologies for the lack of clarity. And this algorithm is indeed a snippet from this exact algorithm you thought about. Any idea on how to do that better is appreciated.

Comment: Code looks very broken to me (e.g. that `while` loop condition !). I suggest looking for a better example to work with.

Comment: What's the signature of the `GetRGB()` and `SetRGB()`  functions?   And on which exact line does the error occur?

Comment: That code slightly looks like snippet from badly broken naive flood-fill algorithm but it is too few to tell for sure.

Comment: @LogicStuff it's answerable - not easily, granted, but I've seen worse

Answer (score 4):

The error messages suggests that the `GetRGB` function is expecting the RGB parameters to be `BYTE&`, i.e. references to bytes.

You should therefore declare your local `r`, `g` and `b` variables accordingly, and just pass them straight to the function:

```
BYTE r, g, b;
scr->GetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, r, g, b);
```

Your `while` loop is also broken - you need to use `&&` or `||` to join the three conditions, not the `,` operator.

Comment: When I do that, the code compiler and the program runs, but activating this function causes an unhandled exception.

Comment: @Erthain when you do what exactly, and what exception, at what line?

Comment: @Erthain but at a guess, you're exceeding the bounds of the image...

Comment: @Erthain it's also possible you should be using `||` rather than `&&` if the intent is to detect any non-black pixel

Comment: Unless I am more retarded than I assume I am, I cannot specify that exception: its a runtime thing and it just gives me the memory location. Look over the two other functions, I think they give the security measure for the image size.

Comment: @Erthain right, but you've got no logic in the fill function to check that `x` and `y` stay within those bounds, and if they exceed it there's that call to `IERROR`.  Your debugger _should_ be giving you a traceback.

Comment: Debugger does give me a traceback to the line: scr->GetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, r, g, b);, but not to the IERROR. You think its that, or should it trace to the IERROR directly in the function? By the way, thank you for your patience ^^

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting the error for this line:

```
scr->GetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, (byte)& r, (byte)& g, (byte)& b);
```

The last three arguments are addresses and you try to cast them into values.
I think this will resolve your error:

```
scr->GetRGB(mid.x, mid.y, (byte*)& r, (byte*)& g, (byte*)& b);
```

Comment: ITYM just `&r` - if `GetRGB` expects a `byte*` then there's no need for the cast.

Comment: and in fact it appears to be expecting a `BYTE&`

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure... maybe the compiler refers to the &r as BYTE& expression? We need to see the GetRGB signature to be sure.

Comment: I added the function you asked about. Please refer to the edited text and thank you for your assistance.